# initial mobile screen doesn't scroll

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

The template i'm using doesn't allow scrolling on load.  You can only touch scroll after you have selected a collapsed menu item.  Once you scroll back to the top it "locks" again (so-to-speak).

The main area that seems to be unscrollable is a slider.  Can anyone tell me what I need to do to make this site be scrollable on load?

Any information is greatly appreciated.

The site is here...  http://www.slicemfg.com

```
    <div id="home">                 
            <div class="tp-banner-container">
                <div class="tp-banner" >                
                    <ul>
                        <!-- THE FIRST SLIDE -->

                        <li data-transition="zoomout" data-slotamount="4" data-masterspeed="700">
                            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" /> }
                            <!-- THE CAPTIONS IN THIS SLIDE -->
                            <div class="caption big-text lft"  
                                 data-x="center" 
                                 data-y="350"
                                 width="10px" 
                                 data-speed="700" 
                                 data-start="700" 
                                 data-easing="easeOutExpo">
                    <div class="big-text"><span4>YOUR IDEAS REALIZED</span4></br><div><a class="button3 scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT US</a></div></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>   

                        <li data-transition="zoomout" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="700">
                            <img src="images/14.jpg" alt="" />
                            <div class="just_pattern"></div>

                            <div class="caption big-text lft"  
                                 data-x="center" 
                                 data-y="center" 
                                 data-speed="700" 
                                 data-start="700" 
                                 data-easing="easeOutExpo"><div class="big-text"><span4>YOUR IDEAS REALIZED</span4></br><div><a class="button3 scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT US</a></div></div>
                            </div>

                        </li>


                        <li data-transition="zoomout" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="700">
                            <img src="images/07.jpg" alt="" />
                            <div class="just_pattern"></div>

                            <div class="caption big-text lft"  
                                 data-x="center" 
                                 data-y="center" 
                                 data-speed="700" 
                                 data-start="700" 
                                 data-easing="easeOutExpo"><div class="big-text"><span4>YOUR IDEAS REALIZED</span4></br><div><a class="button3 scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT US</a></div></div>
                            </div>

                        </li>



                        <li data-transition="zoomout" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="700">                       
                            <img src="images/04.jpg" alt="" />
                            <div class="just_pattern"></div>


                            <div class="caption big-text lft"  
                                 data-x="center" 
                                 data-y="center" 
                                 data-speed="500" 
                                 data-start="500" 
                                 data-easing="easeOutExpo"><div class="big-text"><span4>YOUR IDEAS REALIZED</span4></br><div><a class="button3 scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT US</a></div></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>                              
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, you need to add `touchenabled:"off",` to your revolution config.

Your config should now look like this:

```
(function($) { "use strict";
var revapi;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  revapi = jQuery('.tp-banner').revolution(
      {
          delay:5000,
          startwidth:2000,
          startheight:500,
          soloArrowRightVOffset:50,
          soloArrowLeftVOffset:50,
          hideThumbs:0,
          onHoverStop:"off",
          navigationType: "none",
          fullWidth:"off",
          fullScreen:"on",
          fullScreenOffsetContainer: "",
          touchenabled:"off" //Disable touch events.
      });

}); //ready
```

})(jQuery);